# I want to color format, the repeated names With LT and UA assistance, using formula and conditional format

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, duplicates, formatting, cell

I have 6 columns, Firs name, Last name, date, attendance code, Shift and ID. I want to color formatting, the repeated names With LT and UA assistance, using formula and conditional format. Please let me know if is possible.

The condition is if in attendance is "LT" Format the All the names in color...

```
LAST NAME - FIRST NAME - DATE - ATTENDANCE - SHIFT - ID
Davis  -   John  -   03/03/24   -   LT    - 2ND -    1001
Davis  -   John  -   03/04/24   -   XX    - 2ND -    1001 
Davis  -   John  -   03/05/24   -   XX    - 2ND -    1001
Davis  -   John  -   03/06/24   -   XX    - 2ND -    1001
```

Comment: Sounds like applying conditional formatting, equal to or text equal to should work.

Comment: As @SolarMike has said, this sounds pretty possible. If you'd like further advice, edit your response and add some example data - here are some guidelines if you need assistance with that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example